# Invalid email address characters cause SQL database failure

Tags: sql, regex, mass-emails

I found a link discussing regex for defining valid email addresses.

http://regular-expressions.mobi/email.html

It says that this is a RFC 2822 standard that defines a valid email address. But, it explains that some characters, such as ' may make a SQL database fail. Is there a solution in SQL that will accept such email addresses?

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have this problem with any data that you try and insert directly into an SQL database. There will be an escape character, normally `\` that you can precede problem characters such as `'` so that they work.

Comment: For all non-alphanumeric characters,  for SQL proposes, should I add a \ in front?

Comment: It depends on which database engine you use, and is therefore out of scope for this section of Stack Exchange